# how to remove null values from an sql pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i replace the null values with zero in the sql pivot table?

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[Offer_cover]) 
            FROM #cover2 c 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT Ref,role_name,offer_id, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select*
                from #cover2 
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 SUM(cover_earning_Count)
                for [offer_cover] in (' + @cols + ') 
            ) p   '
execute(@query)
```

Output:

```
Ref         role_name    offer_id   10000   104000  112000
43132_43282 Call Center  1          1       NULL    NULL
43132_43282 Others       1          2       NULL    NULL
43160_43282 Call Center  1          6       NULL    1
43160_43282 Others       1          NULL    1       NULL
43191_43282 Call Center  1          7       NULL    NULL
43191_43282 Others       1          3       1       1
43221_43282 Call Center  1          4       1       1
43221_43282 Others       1          2       NULL    NULL
```

## Cover2 Table

```
Ref YEAR    MONTH   Role_name   offer_cover offer_id    Cover_Earning_Count CONF_DATE   Curr_date
43132_43282 2018    2   Call Center 2000    1   5   2/1/2018    7/1/2018
43132_43282 2018    2   Call Center 4000    1   8   2/1/2018    7/1/2018
43132_43282 2018    2   Call Center 6000    1   2   2/1/2018    7/1/2018
43132_43282 2018    2   Call Center 8000    1   4   2/1/2018    7/1/2018
43132_43282 2018    2   Call Center 10000   1   1   2/1/2018    7/1/2018
43132_43282 2018    2   Call Center 12000   1   6   2/1/2018    7/1/2018
43132_43282 2018    2   Call Center 14000   1   2   2/1/2018    7/1/2018
43132_43282 2018    2   Call Center 16000   1   4   2/1/2018    7/1/2018
43132_43282 2018    2   Call Center 20000   1   6   2/1/2018    7/1/2018
43132_43282 2018    2   Call Center 24000   1   5   2/1/2018    7/1/2018
```

Comment: you need to use `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` on the `SELECT` clause. So you will need 2 `@cols`. One for the `PIVOT`, one for the `SELECT`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as i have mention earlier in my comments, you need 2 @cols, one for the select and another for the pivot

```
 DECLARE @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX),   -- for pivot
         @cols2  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),   -- for select
         @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[Offer_cover]) 
            FROM #cover2 c 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

-- this is for the SELECT
SET @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(c.[Offer_cover]) + ', 0) ' + QUOTENAME(c.[Offer_cover])
            FROM #cover2 c 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Ref,role_name,offer_id, ' + @cols2 + ' from 
            (
                select *
                from #cover2 
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 SUM(cover_earning_Count)
                 for [Offer_cover] in (' + @cols + ') 
            ) p'

-- do a print to verify the query
print @query
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ISNULL`

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[Offer_cover]) 
            FROM #Table1 c 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT Ref,role_name,offer_id, ' + isnull(@cols,0) + ' from 
            (
                select*
                from #Table1 
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 SUM(cover_earning_Count)
                for [offer_cover] in (' + @cols + ') 
            ) p   '
execute(@query)
```

Comment: i doubt this will work. `@cols` is a string of column name in csv

Comment: you can't use the same @cols for the `SELECT` & `PIVOT`. The `PIVOT` part cannot contain the `ISNULL()` . Also the `isnull(@cols,0)` in the `@query` is not required

Comment: @Chanukya This is not working. I have tried this in my code already :(

Comment: @AlankarGupta please post some data of temparory table

Comment: @Chanukya Added

Comment: @AlankarGupta my answer and squirel answer getting same results